# Getting an Unexpected Token Var Error in JS

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

**Problem**
I have tried looking at the other solutions here but nothing is seeming to work for me. My problem is that I'm getting an unexpected var token on line 43, but I can't find any unclosed brackets or parentheses. I've tried deleting line by line, but the problem only starts on that line. If I delete line 43 the line above it has an unexpected ")" token and I can't figure that one out either. This is the code

**CODE**

```js
// FUNCTION DEFINITION(S)
function map(array, callbackFunction) {
  var newArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArray = newArray + callbackFunction(element);
  }

  return newArray;
}

function cubeAll(numbers) {
  return map(numbers, function(n) {
    return n * n * n;
  });
}

// ASSERTION FUNCTION(S) TO BE USED
function assertArraysEqual (actual, expected, testName) {

  var allValuesAreEqual = true

  for (x = 0; x < actual.length; x++) {
    var actualValues = actual[x];
    var expectedValues = expected[x];
    if (actualvalues !== expectedValues) {
      allValuesAreEqual = false
      break;
    }
  }
  if (allValuesAreEqual === true) {
    console.log('passed')
  } else {
    console.log ('FAILED [' + testName + '] expected ' + expected + ', but got ' + actual + '.')
  }
}

// TESTS CASES
var numbers = [2, 3, 4];
var output = function cubeAll(numbers)
var actual = function map(output, cubeAll)
```

Comment: Which one is line 43?

Comment: Wait, `var output = function cubeAll(numbers)`? That's not how you call a function, it's just `var output = cubeAll(numbers)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to ***run*** functions in your test cases, but you're using the `function` keyword, which ***defines*** functions.

`function` keyword expects a function definition (e.g. `{somecode()}`) before the next statement, but instead of finding a `{`, it finds the keyword `var` on the next line.

#### Solution

```
var output = cubeAll(numbers)
var actual = map(output, cubeAll)
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be something simple, but I was just not seeing it.